# RPG embedded SQL - Fetching and updating rows

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

I want to fecth rows and update them in RPG (free).
Using old style opcodes I'd do that:

```
READE %KDS(KEY) FILE;
processRecord();
UPDATE FILE;
```

Problems come with SQL opcodes:

```
EXEC SQL FETCH MYCURSOR INTO :VAR;
processRecord();
????
```

Using `EXEC SQL UPDATE FILE... SET... WHERE KEY...` return an SQLCOD error.
Is there a particular technique?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By reading "Programming in RPG IV", I found an answer.

```
EXEC SQL DECLARE MYCURSOR CURSOR FOR *SELECT STATEMENT* FOR UPDATE OF *FIELDS*;
EXEC SQL OPEN MYCURSOR;
EXEC SQL FETCH MYCURSOS INTO :VARIABLE;
EXEC SQL UPDATE FILE SET *FIELDS* WHERE CURRENT OF MYCURSOR;
EXEC SQL CLOSE MYCURSOR;
```

That's it, pretty straightforward!